# Join a JSON object of arrays and reduce down to one key

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Given that I have a dataset as follows:

```
{ 1: ['Extremely Tall'], 2: ['Tall'], 3: ['Medium', 'Low'], 4: ['Dwarf'] }
```

and I receive a value (e.g. Tall or Medium) I want to determine the associated key. By the way feel free to change the dataset, i.e. it doesn't have to be a json object... so long as:

```
Medium -> 3
Low -> 3
Tall -> 2
```

My solution is below, anyone have a better way of doing it?

```
const R = require('ramda')
const heightsMap = { 1: ['Extremely Tall'], 2: ['Tall'], 3: ['Medium', 'Low'], 4: ['Dwarf'] }
const height = 'Medium'

const associatedNumber = R.keys(heightsMap).filter(key => heightsMap[key].includes(height))[0]

console.log(associatedNumber)
```

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I am not the downvoter but I see there is 1 vote to close this question due to lack of context. It would be helpful if you could [edit] your post to explain how the data is used after the code above is used. If you haven't already read it, check out [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: well OK.. I'm really not sure what else I could say that would be relevant. I'm going to save the answer to the database but I dont see how that changes the solution

Comment: Have you heard the joke about the person who asks for directions and is told "If I wanted to go there, I wouldn't start here"? More context would help answerers know whether the real solution to propose would be "Don't store your dataset like that".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Review

I'm not a big fan of importing other libraries when a built-in alternative is available.

> ```
> const R = require('ramda')
> ```

`R.keys` could be replaced by `Object.keys`:

```
const associatedNumber = Object.keys(heightsMap)
  .filter(key => heightsMap[key]
  .includes(height))[0]
```

Two improvements can be made. First, you're using `filter` which iterates all elements. This is a pity, since you're only interested in the first item `[0]`. `Find` is the method you were looking for. Second, You're traversing keys to perform another lookup `heightsMap[key]`. This could be done in a single iteration using `Object.entries`.

#### Proposed Rewrite

```
const associatedNumber = Object.entries(heightsMap)
  .find(([key, value]) => value.includes(height))[0];

console.log(associatedNumber);
```

Note that `[0]` in the refactored code gets the `key` of `[key, value]`.